# Command output in variable and suppress standard output

Tags: bash, curl, time

```
time=$(TIMEFORMAT="%R"; { time /usr/bin/time -f "\n%E elapsed" curl -s "https://example.com"; } 2>&1)

ElapsedTime=$(echo "$time" | tail -c 23)
```

This above commands work as expected, however, I don't want echo to print to standard output. I just want value assigned to variable.

Comment: Missing `)` at the end of  `time...`

Comment: `echo` prints to standard output by design otherwise you wouldn't be able to `tail` it. The whole output is assigned to the ElapsedTime variable and not output to the screen. It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @jlliagre `echo` does indeed but the `ElapsedTime` variable is not evaluated.

Comment: What do you mean "not evaluated"?

Comment: @jlliagre what I mean is. `var=$(echo foo)` will hold `foo` thus not print it unless I call `echo "$var"`  So i this case `ElapsedTime` should hold the value but not print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between the first and the second assignment, or with `var=$(echo foo)` as far as standard output is concerned.

In you second instruction:

> ElapsedTime=$(echo "$time" | tail -c 23)

The command standard output which is the pipeline standard output, in this case `tail` stdout, is assigned to the variable content and **not** displayed on screen.

On the other hand, should one of the inner commands output something on its standard error flow, it would be displayed on screen as you do not redirect stderr.

Note that `echo "$time"` is unreliable. I would recommend `printf "%s\n" "$time"` to avoid unexpected side effects of `time` value.

`tail -c -number` is POSIX so I wouldn't expect this command to fail.